# which is faster in a for loop, accessing values using temp variable or the index?

Tags: javascript, performance

I am trying to optimize some knockout js code and I was wondering which would be faster, ie accessing the variable using the indexer as so:

```
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {     

            data[i].MediaID = ko.observable(data[i].MediaID);
            data[i].MediaName= ko.observable(data[i].MediaName);
            data[i].MediaTypeID= ko.observable(data[i].MediaTypeID);

        }
```

or declaring a temp variable.

```
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {             
            var temp = data[i];

            temp.MediaID = ko.observable(temp.MediaID);
            temp.MediaName= ko.observable(temp.MediaName);
            temp.MediaTypeID= ko.observable(temp.MediaTypeID);

        }
```

Comment: Try it on http://jsperf.com

Comment: ^ [JSPerf test](http://jsperf.com/temporary-variable-vs-accessing-array-directly)

Comment: Which one do you find easier to read/write? Use that. The performance difference is negligible [until you realize it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premature_optimisation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accesing with the temp-variable should be slightly faster because you don't need to look up the element in the array.

However, the gain will be minimal

Answer (score 0):

compare

```
        data.a.b.c.d.e.f.g.MediaID = ko.observable(data.a.b.c.d.e.f.g.MediaID);
        data.a.b.c.d.e.f.g.MediaName= ko.observable(data.a.b.c.d.e.f.g.MediaName);
        data.a.b.c.d.e.f.g.MediaTypeID= ko.observable(data.a.b.c.d.e.f.g.MediaTypeID);
```

and

```
        var temp =data.a.b.c.d.e.f.g;

        temp.MediaID = ko.observable(temp.MediaID);
        temp.MediaName= ko.observable(temp.MediaName);
        temp.MediaTypeID= ko.observable(temp.MediaTypeID);
```

you don't need to look up the same thing so many times

Answer (score 0):

if you want it faster you should also cache data.length

```
for(var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++)...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about performance don't use array.length in the loop. That is not a value, is a internal function that everytime that is accessed recount the total items of the array, the better is:

```
var total = items.length;
for(i=0; i < total; i++){
   //stuff
}
```

Now for your specific use case, I do not know the framweworks that you are using on, but if you are using jQuery and / or underscore, instead of a loop, you could use one of the map functions:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/
http://underscorejs.org/#map

Comment: You really think `length` is a function call and includes counting? It's just as optimized as everything else.

Comment: Thank You Jonah for the test case, it demonstrated what I was saying.